# OpenGL, перевод координат экрана

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

У меня на экране отображается диаграмма. Как мне пересчитать экранные координаты точки на диаграмме в физические величины, соответствующие значениям на осях? Я хочу выводить их при движении мышки (которая даёт мне пиксельные координаты).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это диаграмма, то для этого Вам необходимо знать Min и Max физических величин по обеим осям. Отношения разностей этих величин к размерам экрана дадут масштаб (Mx, My)  по обеим осям. Соответствующая абсцисса (Х) физической точки вычисляется по формуле

```
X = Mx * (xp - x0) + MinX, где    
xp - экранная абсцисса точки;
x0 - "нулевая" абсцисса экрана;
MinX - минимум физического экрана.
```

При вычислении физ. ординаты помните, что экранная ордината увеличивается сверху вниз.